# android fingerprint authentication error cannot find symbol method fingerprintHandler

Tags: java, android, authentication, mobile, fingerprint

I had created two java class which are fingerprintActivity and fingerprintHandler in android studio but unfortunately I bump into this error :

> Error:(77, 19) error: cannot find symbol method
>   fingerprintHandler(FingerprintManager,CryptoObject)

I really need help as I'm new in learning android app...

this is my coding for `fingerprintActivity class` :

```
package com.atiemt.elba_employee;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.KeyguardManager;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.hardware.fingerprint.FingerprintManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.security.keystore.KeyGenParameterSpec;
import android.security.keystore.KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException;
import android.security.keystore.KeyProperties;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.NoSuchProviderException;
import java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;

public class FingerprintAuthenticationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String KEY_NAME = "example_key";
private FingerprintManager fingerprintManager;
private KeyguardManager keyguardManager;
private KeyStore keyStore;
private KeyGenerator keyGenerator;
private Cipher cipher;
private FingerprintManager.CryptoObject cryptoObject;
private FingerprintHandler fingerprintHandler;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fingerprint_authentication);

    keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
    fingerprintManager = (FingerprintManager) getSystemService(FINGERPRINT_SERVICE);

    if (!keyguardManager.isKeyguardSecure()) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Lock screen security not enabled in Settings",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Fingerprint authentication permission not enabled",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        return;
    }

    if (!fingerprintManager.hasEnrolledFingerprints()) {

        // This happens when no fingerprints are registered.
        Toast.makeText(this, "Register at least one fingerprint in Settings",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }

    generateKey();
```

/** error at helper.fingerprintHandler */

```
    if (cipherInit()) {
        cryptoObject = new FingerprintManager.CryptoObject(cipher);
        FingerprintHandler helper = new FingerprintHandler(this);
        helper.fingerprintHandler(fingerprintManager,cryptoObject);
    }

}

protected void generateKey() {
    try {
        keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES,
                "AndroidKeyStore");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchProviderException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to get KeyGenerator instance", e);
    }

    try {
        keyStore.load(null);
        keyGenerator.init(new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(KEY_NAME, KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
                .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC)
                .setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)
                .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7)
                .build());
        keyGenerator.generateKey();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException | CertificateException | IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

}

public boolean cipherInit() {
    try {
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES + "/" + KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC + "/"
                        + KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to get Cipher", e);
    }

    try {
        keyStore.load(null);
        SecretKey key = (SecretKey) keyStore.getKey(KEY_NAME,null);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        return true;
    } catch (KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException e) {
        return false;
    } catch (KeyStoreException | CertificateException | UnrecoverableKeyException | IOException
            | NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeyException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to init Cipher", e);
    }
}
```

}

this is coding for fingerprintHandler class :

```
package com.atiemt.elba_employee;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.hardware.fingerprint.FingerprintManager;
import android.os.CancellationSignal;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class FingerprintHandler extends FingerprintManager.AuthenticationCallback {

private CancellationSignal cancellationSignal;
private Context appContext;


public FingerprintHandler(Context context) {
    appContext = context;}


public void startAuth(FingerprintManager manager, FingerprintManager.CryptoObject cryptoObject) {

    cancellationSignal = new CancellationSignal();

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(appContext, Manifest.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT) !=
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    manager.authenticate(cryptoObject, cancellationSignal, 0, this, null);
}

@Override
public void onAuthenticationError(int errMsgId,
                                  CharSequence errString) {
    Toast.makeText(appContext,
            "Authentication error\n" + errString,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onAuthenticationHelp(int helpMsgId,
                                 CharSequence helpString) {
    Toast.makeText(appContext,
            "Authentication help\n" + helpString,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onAuthenticationFailed() {
    Toast.makeText(appContext,
            "Authentication failed.",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onAuthenticationSucceeded(
        FingerprintManager.AuthenticationResult result) {

    Toast.makeText(appContext,
            "Authentication succeeded.",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

}
```

Comment: I think you need to replace the error line (`helper.fingerprintHandler`) with `helper.startAuth`.

Comment: wow thank you so much! @putu it works now... :)